# What is the area for given conic?

Tags: analytic-geometry

I need to Find the area of conic section given by:

$5x^2 - 6xy + 5y^2 = 8$, Using substitution $x = u+ v$ and $y = u-v$ we get :

$5\left(u+v\right)^2 - 6\left(u^2 - v^2\right) + 5\left(u-v\right)^2 = 8$

which simplifies to :

$4u^2 + 16v^2 = 8$

thus, this is an equation of ellipse, $\dfrac{u^2}{2} + \dfrac{v^2}{1/2} = 1$,

Area is given by : $\pi a b  = \pi \sqrt{2} \sqrt{1/2} = \pi$

Is My Solution to given  problem correct ?

Thank you

Comment: Does your substitution preserve lengths?

Comment: @CY Aries: I'm sorry I cannot understand your hint, can you please elaborate ?

Comment: The distance between the points $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and $(x,y)=(1,0)$ is $1$.  The two points are corresponding to $(u,v)=(0,0)$ and $(u,v)=(0.5, 0.5)$. The distance between $(0,0)$ and $(0.5, 0.5)$ is $1/\sqrt{2}$. The lengths change after applying the substitution. So do areas.

Comment: So , I need to multiply my area by the "scaling" Factor ie the value of $\left|J\right|$,where J is the Jacobian of the Transformation $x$ and $y$, Since the value of Jacobian  is  $2$ (After neglecting the signs), the area should be doubled  ?

Comment: Is my reasoning correct ?

Comment: See the first part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3346998/265466) for a way to compute this area directly from the original equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Adding this answer in order that yet another question that was answered in a comment not remain formally unanswered.]

As CY Aries points out in a comment, your transformation isn’t area-preserving. You must either rescale the area computed from the transformed equation by multiplying by the Jacobian determinant of the transformation (as you noted), or use an area-preserving transformation in the first place. The one you used originally is a similarity, so it’s easily adjusted to preserve areas: normalize it to $x={u+v\over\sqrt2}$, $y={u-v\over\sqrt2}$. Either way you’ll end up with twice the area that you computed with your original transformation.